# Why does django.utils.importlib.import_module not import the correct app? And how does the variable change?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-apps, python-import

I was having "models not installed or is abstract" errors that only occur on some machines but not others, and when I delved deeper, I found the problem was the `load_app(self, app_name, can_postpone=False)` method in `django.db.models.loading.py` wasn't working as assumed by django.

In `def load_app(self, app_name, can_postpone=False)` at line 87, I added some print statements.
(Original code here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/loading.py#L87)

```
    self.handled[app_name] = None
    self.nesting_level += 1
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
    print "APP--", app_name
    try:
        print "APPNAME-BEGIN", app_name, type(app_name)
        models = import_module('.models', app_name)
        print "APPNAME-END__", app_name
        print "LOADD", str(models), app_name
    except ImportError, e:
```

You'd think `app_name` at `APPNAME-BEGIN` would be same as `app_name` in `APPNAME-END__`...

Here is the output:

```
2012-12-20 15:44:12.526254500 APPNAME-BEGIN users <type 'str'>
2012-12-20 15:44:12.590877500 APPNAME-END__ gradmaker
2012-12-20 15:44:12.590877500 LOADD <module 'gradmaker.models' from '/home/gradcon4/gradcon4/project/gradmaker/models.pyc'> gradmaker
```

How did `app_name` change? Why was the wrong module imported? (`gradmaker` instead of `users`)

Under what conditions does this occur?

Comment: I highly doubt the django code in this example is wrong. I think the problem must be elsewhere. The chances of such a core piece of django infrastructure containing a bug is slim. Do you want to know why the app_name changes, or do you want to fix your `models not installed or is abstract` error?

Comment: The problem is the import_module importing the wrong module, leading to one models.py not being imported. So I want to figure out what is causing import_module to do this... I have made sure my app is listed in INSTALLED_APPS before any dependent app, the models are concrete, etc, for many times, before delving this deep into django's code.

Most apps are imported correctly. It's just a couple that is experiencing this problem.

Comment: Once again, I don't think it's the `import_module` module doing the wrong thing. Could you post the `models.py` code of the offending module? Also, what version of django are you using? Have you recently started using 1.5? Has `syncdb` been run in all cases?

Comment: It's actually a lot more complicated than my output suggests. the variable didn't change. the `users` app was imported as a result of importing `gradmaker`, and it just never go to print the corresponding `APPNAME-END__` for `users` (but it never got into the except ImportError part of the code either). I suppose it isn't likely there is a bug with `import_module`, but I can't post the `models.py` because this is my company's code. Django 1.4.3 and we're using south (all the tables are there). I'm considering just formatting it and restarting because it works fine on the other server.

Comment: Found it by wrapping all the code inside of load_app with try...except, printing traceback then re-raising errors. 

Somewhere in the code there was this line:

    `import gradmaker.models as gradmaker`

It caused an error that python didn't report because it was caught by some kind of try..except, somewhere. It would explain why I couldn't see the corresponding APPNAME-END__ for users; there was an error that raised the program out of the function.

Changed it to:
    
     `from gradmaker import models as gradmaker`

And now it runs.

Comment: post your answer as an answer then accept it, so others can find it in the future. ALso, consider revising your question and including the exact error you were receiving, so that it's easier to find for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening was one of the `import X` lines were raising an `ImportError`.

i.e `import gradmaker.models as gradmaker` is incorrect, use `from gradmaker import models as gradmaker` instead.

The `ImportError` was caught by one of the functions called by `import_module`, and skipped.

So the app that this error occurred in didn't get imported correctly.

Once the import line is fixed, all was good.

The variable didn't change, what's happened was the code jumped out of a function due to an error, and made weird output.